# Custom chrome for Node Webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Here is what I am aiming to build:

[image]

[Full size of image is here](https://dribbble.com/shots/1032273-Aries-Browser/attachments/124664).

Is this possible to do with Node Webkit? I know I can visit sites, but I want to change the default chrome and add more functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in the node webkit Google Group and they answered my question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-webkit/n6Gy3obE638